# Charge one powerbank from multiple sources

Tags: power-supply, solar-charge-controller, usb-pd

I am in need of more power while traveling and for this purpose I will create a setup with one dynamo hub, one larger solar panel (30W) on the back of the bike and a smaller (10W) solar panel in front.

How can all power harvested be channelled to one USB QC port and/or DC 20V?

Note: the 10W solar panel has a broken controller and it needs to be changed. The 30W controller most likely will be swapped with a controller with DC output since currently it does output max 18W per USB port. I will buy controllers from China soon, but perhaps the solution is to have the outputs of the panels and dynamo into one controller?

The 10W solar panel is polycrystalline [same model as this one, with only 2 folds](https://www.decathlon.fr/p/panneau-solaire-usb-15w-slr900-v2/_/R-p-345095?mc=8788791).

The 30W panel is monocrystalline. [This model](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/SUPAREE-Charger-Portable-Monocrystalline-Travel-30w/dp/B091YWFYS6)